# Multiple screenshots using ScreenDC, wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I ran into a problem with ScreenDC in wxPython Phoenix.

My tool is supposed to take multiple screenshots with some period. But whenever I use ScreenDC to grab a screenshot and save it to PNG it works well only for the first time. All the following times it just saves the same image as the first one. To get a new image, I have to restart the program, which is not an option in my case. I guess that whenever I call `wx.ScreenDC()` it gets the same image as the first time.

Ubuntu 16.04, wxPython 3.0.3 gtk3, python 3.6

The code I used:

```
def take_screenshot():
    screen = wx.ScreenDC()
    size = screen.GetSize()
    width = size[0]
    height = size[1]
    bmp = wx.Bitmap(width, height)
    mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
    mem.Blit(0, 0, width, height, screen, 0, 0)
    bmp.SaveFile(str(datetime.now()) + '.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    take_screenshot()
    sleep(3)
    take_screenshot()
    sleep(3)
    take_screenshot()
    sleep(3)
    take_screenshot()
```

Maybe there is the way to clean that first image from memory.

The only solution I found is to run a separate process, define wx.App inside and then to perform the function. However, that is not an option for my program.

Thanks.

**UPD**: It seems to be some issue of wxPython Phoenix. If you run this on wxPython Classic, everything works fine(just use EmptyBitmap, not Bitmap).  Weird, I will report this issue in their repository.

Comment: See also on [Github](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/259)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your issue in Phoenix or Classic (on Windows). I suppose what could happen is that `sleep` blocks wxPython event loop. It would be good style to put long-running things in a separate thread anyway. It is painless, see below.

```
from threading import Thread

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    def payload():
        take_screenshot()
        sleep(3)
        take_screenshot()
        sleep(3)
        take_screenshot()
        sleep(3)
        take_screenshot()
    thrd = Thread(target=payload)
    thrd.start()
```

EDIT: As the asker pointed out, there may be issues with thread-safety in the approach above. How does the thing work below for you (tested on Phoenix and Classic on Windows)?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import wx
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

IS_PHOENIX = True if 'phoenix' in wx.version() else False

if IS_PHOENIX:
    EmptyBitmap = lambda *args, **kwds: wx.Bitmap(*args, **kwds)
else:
    EmptyBitmap = lambda *args, **kwds: wx.EmptyBitmap(*args, **kwds)

def take_screenshot():
    screen = wx.ScreenDC()
    size = screen.GetSize()
    width = size[0]
    height = size[1]
    bmp = EmptyBitmap(width, height)
    mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
    mem.Blit(0, 0, width, height, screen, 0, 0)
    bmp.SaveFile(str(datetime.now().second) + '.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)

MAXPICS = 4

class testfrm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.tmr = wx.Timer(self, -1)
        self.countpics = 0
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.ontimer, self.tmr)
        self.ontimer(None)

    def ontimer(self, evt):
        if self.countpics <=MAXPICS:
            self.tmr.Start(3000, wx.TIMER_ONE_SHOT)
            take_screenshot()
            self.countpics += 1
        else:
            self.Close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = testfrm(None, -1, wx.version())
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I tried working without sleep(), but the result was just the same.

Also, Threads should be used very carefully for wxPython GUI, read here: https://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui. In this case     `bmp.SaveFile(...)` should be called from main thread or you will get multithreading C errors. This seems to be issue only on Linux, didn't have these errors on Windows.

I ended up changing to python 2, it was easy enough.

Comment: So, would you mind posting the traceback? And the mainloop needs to be in the main Thread. It is not impossible to make calls to wx from a Thread as long as things are kept thread-safe.